# USB Debugging Error but WIFI Debugging clearly Fine :( how to fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin, adb

I want to debug using my USB Port, but the adb or something hold me an error. In other condition, when i used my Wifi/Wireless Debugging, the app running well.

I screenshot the messages Event Log my Android Studio on below, Check out.

[These Messages are from my Event Log - Newest Version Android Studio Chipmunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssff2.jpg)

My ADB could detected my devices, but always looping connect and disconnect, like infinite loop.

this is my output event log in code format.

```
08.30   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

08.30   * daemon started successfully

08.30   Adb connection Error:EOF

08.30   Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused

08.30   Failed to start monitoring CMDAT4NRGMAMBY9T

08.30   Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

08.30   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

08.30   * daemon started successfully

08.30   Adb connection Error:EOF

08.30   Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused

08.30   Failed to start monitoring CMDAT4NRGMAMBY9T

08.30   Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

08.30   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
```

Comment: Try changing cords.

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screenshot. You can simply copy the output to clipboard and paste it as text into your question (and format it as code). BTW: What OS do you use?

Comment: @Robert oh my, im sorry. i'll edit my output screenshot to code format immidiately. im using mac os monterey. idk, my usb debugging was like refused my phone redmi, and i considered that was my phone problem not the adb stuff. but it still error.

Comment: @DanHarms, thankyou for reply. but what should i do with the cords? i didn't know.

Comment: I meant try using a different cord and see if it is still happening.